# REST API GET/POST using jquery AJAX to get node using neo4j graph database

Tags: rest, jquery, post, neo4j

I'm new to REST API**(is that really my REST problem?)**

I want to get all node from neo4js by using 
Cypher

```
START n = node(*)
return n;
```

**how do i use if i use jquery ajax POST or GET method**

in [doc](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html) it recommend

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

In my code i write

```
 $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
      accepts: "application/json",
      dataType:"json",
      contentType:"application/json",
      data:{
             "query" : "start n  = node(*) return n",
             "params" : {}
           },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                      alert(textStatus);
                        },
      error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                       alert(textStatus);
                        }
             });//end of placelist ajax
```

What's my problem?
The error alert is below
[image]

Comment: Just a small comment regarding the error.  You should place errorThrown in the alert, to display the actual error message.

Comment: in errorThrown, it show nothing (just blank), where's the actual msg?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont say what kind of error you get, but running exactly the same code as you, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/cypher.
Origin http://127.0.0.1:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So I am assuming that this is the error you are experiencing.

When performing a cross-domain Ajax call, there are two options:

1. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which Neo4J does not support.
2. Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). ["The basic idea behind CORS is to use custom HTTP headers to allow both the browser and the server to know enough about each other to determine if the request or response should succeed or fail"](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/).

The OPTIONS request sent before the POST ([preflight request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request)), returns the following headers from the Neo4J REST server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:OPTIONS,POST
Server:Jetty(6.1.25)
```

A cruical header is missing here, namely the `Content-Type` header.  This means that the POST request will fail when this header is sent with the POST request, which is exactly what is happening in your $.ajax() call.

The POST will succeed if you remove the following line

```
contentType:"application/json",
```

from your `$.ajax()` call.

This will prevent jQuery from sending the Content-Type header.

Comment: error means cannot works, it lead to error section.But i'm using linux server, any differenet with windows while using localhost? And i remove the contentType still not working =(

Comment: sorry!i misunderstand, i remove the contentType and it's work, but can u explain more detail because i don't understand why

Comment: "The POST will succeed if you remove the following line
contentType:"application/json"" ---> good way for me ! Really thanks